# How do I run multiple scripts within a script, even if one script fails

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, exit-code

I have a simple bash script that executes a number of other scripts …

```
#/bin/bash
…
./update_artifact1.sh $ARTIFACT_VERSION
./update_artifact2.sh $ARTIFACT_VERSION
./update_artifact3.sh $ARTIFACT_VERSION
```

The problem is, if the first command (or second) dies with an error, none of the subsequent commands are run.  Is there a way I can run all three commands, save the exit status of each, and then return a successful exit status if all three execute successfully?  The scripts don’t have to run concurrently.

Comment: What you show does not indicate that the main script should die. What is behind "…"?

Comment: If the command "./update_artifact1.sh $ARTIFACT_VERSION" fails, the other two commands ("./update_artifact2.sh $ARTIFACT_VERSION" and "./update_artifact3.sh $ARTIFACT_VERSION") don't run.  Do you understand?

Comment: yes I do. But if you try `cd /unknown_dir; echo ok`, the echo command executed even though cd failed. **Why** do the 2nd and 3rd commands fail in your script? Do you have `set -e` turned on? Do the 2nd and 3rd commands rely on something the 1st provides? Is there any error output? You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly modify your script in this way

```
#!/bin/bash
…
./update_artifact1.sh $ARTIFACT_VERSION
exit_state_1=$?
./update_artifact2.sh $ARTIFACT_VERSION
exit_state_2=$?
./update_artifact3.sh $ARTIFACT_VERSION
exit_state_3=$?
exit_state_all=$[ $exit_state_1 &&  $exit_state_2 && $exit_state_3 ]
exit $exit_state_all
```

**Note:**

- Each command return an exit code that `bash` stores in `$?`. It is `0` if there is no error, or a different number if there is an error.
  After every line the value of `$?` is updated so you need to store in a variable (in this case we used `exit_state_1` ... `exit_state_n`).
  At the end you want that your script will return you only an error code with 0 if it is all ok and we realize it with `$[ $a || $b || $c ]`.
  Note that `$[ 0|| 0 || 0 ]` is 0 meanwhile `$[ $a || $b || $c ]` with at least one on `$a,$b,$c` not equal to `0` returns 1.
- It is important the **!** in the first line when you have to write `#!/bin/bash` to say to the system that is a script that have to be executed in a `bash` shell.
  You may find interesting to read more about the [*shebang* here.](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/)
- As noted in a comment too if you put `set -e` somewhere in your script before those line, the script will be interrupted at the first error without process the other line, and it will return an error code (the one of the last command executed).